# My files keep getting encrypted with the Rakhni Ransomware

Tags: security, encryption, virus, virus-removal

I used the RakhniDecryptor to decrypt my files, but they keep getting encrypted.

I used multiple scanners to search for the Rakhni**Encryptor** on my PC:  Malwarebytes/SuperantiSpyware/NOD32/Kaspersky Malware Scanner.

But, no luck. I used RakhniDecryptor to decrypt, but don't want to keep doing that.

Any suggestions?

Usefull links:

- https://www.nomoreransom.org/

Comment: This may sounds weird but if a PC has ever been infected with anything, the safest method is nuke it from orbit... have you considered wiping and starting over? (after decrypting everything, and copying all content off the HDD, maybe to an external HDD, or even better, use a LiveCD/LiveUSB of a linux variant, to copy the content over to ensure it cannot get re-encrypted while being copied) - then check the content ensuring it is not encrypted, and then wipe and reinstall.

Comment: @Darius Getting a new [Linux] machine soon. For now, just need it to keep going. Reinstalling takes to much time, and I have none, at the moment.